# node.js cannot open filenames with non ascii characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, non-ascii-characters

using node.js on Windows 10, I'm trying to open files with non-ascii characters in the filename. Node says the files do not exist. for example:

```
var songfile = "G:/Music/Music/113/113 degrÃ©s/03 36 quai des orfevres.mp3"    

fs.open(songfile, 'r', function(err, fd) {
  if (err) winston.error('file does not exist: ', songfile);
  else winston.info('file exists: ', fd);
});
```

is there a way around this?

Comment: Why isn't the path wrapped in quotes? You should get syntax error.

Comment: sorry, I typed it up and forgot them. I'm actually working with filepaths pulled from a mongodb. All the ascii filenames work, the non-ascii ones don't

Comment: Are you sure this file really exits on this path? Maybe try replacing "/" with "\\"?

Comment: First: JavaScript typically expects encoding to be UTF-8. Second, as @Gothdo suggests: Windows paths typically use backslashes.

Comment: Hi Gothdo and Burki, I think you're both correct. Basically I'm taking thousands of filepaths from  iTunes and passing them to a cmd exec. I am unescaping them so they are read by the cmd (fpcalc)

The (correct) path is:
G:\Music\Music\113\113 degrés/03 36 quai des orfevres.mp3

itunes escapes it : 
G:/Music/Music/113/113%20degr%C3%A9s/03%2036%20quai%20des%20orfevres.mp3

I use node "unescape" to create a format accepted by cmd. 
G:/Music/Music/113/113 degrÃ©s/03 36 quai des orfevres.mp3

the "unescape" function converted %C3%A9 into Ã© instead of é. I'm not familiar with encoding to know why.